# Rails 3: ":method => :post" doesn't work... seems to be 'GET' when it should 'POST'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to implement the "Friendship" in my Rails 3 app as described in **[Railscast 163:Self Referential Assosication](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association)**

I have everything set up as described. I am using a basic user model that logis in with Authlogic which works fine. However when I try to add a friend using the following link:

```
<% for user in @users %>   
 <%=h user.username %> 
  <%= link_to "Add Friend", friendships_path(:friend_id => user), :method => :post %>     
<% end %>
```

I get a redirect to `http://localhost:3000/friendships?friend_id=2` and a **Unknown action The action 'index' could not be found for FriendshipsController** error with no further explanation. This is expecially strange since I have a hard coded redirect back to the "User#show" method for my current user (i.e. redirect back to profile after adding friend).

If it helps, here is my "friendships#create" method:

```
def create  
  @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])  
  if @friendship.save  
    flash[:notice] = "Added friend."  
    redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id =>'current_user'
  else  
    flash[:notice] = "Unable to add friend."  
    redirect_to :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id =>'current_user' 
  end  
end
```

Any idea what could be causing this? I found someone having a similar problem here but I couldn't find a definite fix: [Rails 3 and Friendship Models](http://www.mentby.com/peng-zhong/rails-3-and-friendship-models.html)

Thanks in advance for your help!

~Dan

Comment: Can you post the HTML that the above link_to ends up generating (i.e. view-source of the web output)?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/796758 heres a full source of the generated output.

Comment: Is the `rails.js` helper file (that actually implements `:method => :post`) being referenced from your HTML?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that link_to  put the arguments into the query string as it is creating with html link  even if you put :method => :post if js is disabled.

you could simulte a post with javascript :onclik event.

aniway , use a link_to with method :post is generaly a bad idea.
in rails you could use **button_to**  helper for this pourpose and style it like a link.

edit:
In Rails3 doc seems that link_to have to simulate the same behaviur of button_to when called with params :method=>:post

> (dynamically create an HTML form and
>   immediately submit the form ).

but it's not true for me in Rails 3.0.3 even if javascript is enabled.
I will investigate.

anyway **you should be using buttons and forms for anything that isn't a GET; hyperlinks intentionally don't allow for methods other than GET**

edit2:
ok,
rails3 don't create a inline form for simulate the post request via link.  in Rails3 a data-method=post attribute is added to the  tag for manipulate it via javascript function.   this way the request gracefully degradate in a get call if js is disabled.

Comment: This works great! Any idea why the link_to method functions differently than the button_to from a programming standpoint? What exactly is going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 5):

It's a late answer but it's a solution to this problem (at least it works for me):

```
<%= link_to "Add Friend", {:controller => :friendships, :action => :create, :friend_id => user_id }, :method => :post %>
```

I know it's long overdue for your problem, but it may help someone :)

Comment: You should mention, it is the extra brackets that do the trick, it makes sure `method: :post` is not seen as an url_option, but a html option.