# `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]` Routing Issue In Heroku, but Works on Localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have voting established in my app via the `Thumbs_Up` gem.  It is working perfectly on my `localhost` but when I try to up/down vote something on `Heroku` I get this error in my `Heroku` logs:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/jokes/wise-police-officer/vote_up"):
```

Here are my routes for the `jokes` model:

```
resources :jokes do
  patch :approve, on: :member
  patch :reject, on: :member
  member do
    post :vote_up
    post :vote_down
  end
end
```

Again, this is strange because it works fine in `localhost`.  Has anyone had a similar problem?

Here's the HTML/ERB for the voting links:

```
        <div class="width: 100%"><%= link_to " ", vote_up_joke_path(joke), class: 'upvote glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up', method: :post, style: "margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" %></div>
        <div class="width: 100%"><h3 style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><strong><%= joke.plusminus %></strong></h3></div>
        <div class="width: 100%"><%= link_to " ", vote_down_joke_path(joke), class: 'downvote glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down', method: :post, style: "margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" %></div>
```

And here's the entirety of my `bundle exec rake routes` output:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                          Controller#Action
                ckeditor        /ckeditor                            Ckeditor::Engine
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)             devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)             devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)            devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)        devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)       devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)              registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                     registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)             registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                     registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                     registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                     registrations#destroy
       user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)        devise/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format)    devise/confirmations#new
                         GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)        devise/confirmations#show
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                 users#show
              home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)                home#index
                    root GET    /                                    home#index
          home_lifehacks GET    /home/lifehacks(.:format)            home#lifehacks
            home_mangear GET    /home/mangear(.:format)              home#mangear
         home_gifthelper GET    /home/gifthelper(.:format)           home#gifthelper
       home_commandments GET    /home/commandments(.:format)         home#commandments
            gifts_babies GET    /gifts/babies(.:format)              gifts#babies
              gifts_kids GET    /gifts/kids(.:format)                gifts#kids
             gifts_teens GET    /gifts/teens(.:format)               gifts#teens
            gifts_adults GET    /gifts/adults(.:format)              gifts#adults
              principles GET    /principles(.:format)                principles#index
        principles_intro GET    /principles/intro(.:format)          principles#intro
 principles_intermediate GET    /principles/intermediate(.:format)   principles#intermediate
     principles_advanced GET    /principles/advanced(.:format)       principles#advanced
         principles_beef GET    /principles/beef(.:format)           principles#beef
      principles_chicken GET    /principles/chicken(.:format)        principles#chicken
         principles_pork GET    /principles/pork(.:format)           principles#pork
         principles_fish GET    /principles/fish(.:format)           principles#fish
      principles_recipes GET    /principles/recipes(.:format)        principles#recipes
      archive_suggestion PATCH  /suggestions/:id/archive(.:format)   suggestions#archive
    unarchive_suggestion PATCH  /suggestions/:id/unarchive(.:format) suggestions#unarchive
             suggestions GET    /suggestions(.:format)               suggestions#index
                         POST   /suggestions(.:format)               suggestions#create
              suggestion DELETE /suggestions/:id(.:format)           suggestions#destroy
    suggestions_archives GET    /suggestions/archives(.:format)      suggestions#archives
               man_tests POST   /man_tests(.:format)                 man_tests#create
            new_man_test GET    /man_tests/new(.:format)             man_tests#new
          man_tests_fail GET    /man_tests/fail(.:format)            man_tests#fail
            approve_joke PATCH  /jokes/:id/approve(.:format)         jokes#approve
             reject_joke PATCH  /jokes/:id/reject(.:format)          jokes#reject
            vote_up_joke POST   /jokes/:id/vote_up(.:format)         jokes#vote_up
          vote_down_joke POST   /jokes/:id/vote_down(.:format)       jokes#vote_down
                   jokes GET    /jokes(.:format)                     jokes#index
                         POST   /jokes(.:format)                     jokes#create
                new_joke GET    /jokes/new(.:format)                 jokes#new
               edit_joke GET    /jokes/:id/edit(.:format)            jokes#edit
                    joke GET    /jokes/:id(.:format)                 jokes#show
                         PATCH  /jokes/:id(.:format)                 jokes#update
                         PUT    /jokes/:id(.:format)                 jokes#update
                         DELETE /jokes/:id(.:format)                 jokes#destroy
              home_jokes GET    /home/jokes(.:format)                home#jokes
         otherjokes_kids GET    /otherjokes/kids(.:format)           otherjokes#kids
        otherjokes_mixed GET    /otherjokes/mixed(.:format)          otherjokes#mixed
          otherjokes_men GET    /otherjokes/men(.:format)            otherjokes#men
     otherjokes_comeback GET    /otherjokes/comeback(.:format)       otherjokes#comeback
          approve_recipe PATCH  /recipes/:id/approve(.:format)       recipes#approve
           reject_recipe PATCH  /recipes/:id/reject(.:format)        recipes#reject
          vote_up_recipe POST   /recipes/:id/vote_up(.:format)       recipes#vote_up
        vote_down_recipe POST   /recipes/:id/vote_down(.:format)     recipes#vote_down
                 recipes GET    /recipes(.:format)                   recipes#index
                         POST   /recipes(.:format)                   recipes#create
              new_recipe GET    /recipes/new(.:format)               recipes#new
             edit_recipe GET    /recipes/:id/edit(.:format)          recipes#edit
                  recipe GET    /recipes/:id(.:format)               recipes#show
                         PATCH  /recipes/:id(.:format)               recipes#update
                         PUT    /recipes/:id(.:format)               recipes#update
                         DELETE /recipes/:id(.:format)               recipes#destroy
                home_bbq GET    /home/bbq(.:format)                  home#bbq
       other_recipes_all GET    /other_recipes/all(.:format)         other_recipes#all
      other_recipes_beef GET    /other_recipes/beef(.:format)        other_recipes#beef
   other_recipes_chicken GET    /other_recipes/chicken(.:format)     other_recipes#chicken
      other_recipes_fish GET    /other_recipes/fish(.:format)        other_recipes#fish
other_recipes_other_meat GET    /other_recipes/other_meat(.:format)  other_recipes#other_meat
   other_recipes_veggies GET    /other_recipes/veggies(.:format)     other_recipes#veggies
            approve_rule PATCH  /rules/:id/approve(.:format)         rules#approve
             reject_rule PATCH  /rules/:id/reject(.:format)          rules#reject
            vote_up_rule POST   /rules/:id/vote_up(.:format)         rules#vote_up
          vote_down_rule POST   /rules/:id/vote_down(.:format)       rules#vote_down
                   rules GET    /rules(.:format)                     rules#index
                         POST   /rules(.:format)                     rules#create
                new_rule GET    /rules/new(.:format)                 rules#new
               edit_rule GET    /rules/:id/edit(.:format)            rules#edit
                    rule GET    /rules/:id(.:format)                 rules#show
                         PATCH  /rules/:id(.:format)                 rules#update
                         PUT    /rules/:id(.:format)                 rules#update
                         DELETE /rules/:id(.:format)                 rules#destroy
               reminders GET    /reminders(.:format)                 reminders#index
                         POST   /reminders(.:format)                 reminders#create
            new_reminder GET    /reminders/new(.:format)             reminders#new
           edit_reminder GET    /reminders/:id/edit(.:format)        reminders#edit
                reminder GET    /reminders/:id(.:format)             reminders#show
                         PATCH  /reminders/:id(.:format)             reminders#update
                         PUT    /reminders/:id(.:format)             reminders#update
                         DELETE /reminders/:id(.:format)             reminders#destroy

Routes for Ckeditor::Engine:
        pictures GET    /pictures(.:format)             ckeditor/pictures#index
                 POST   /pictures(.:format)             ckeditor/pictures#create
         picture DELETE /pictures/:id(.:format)         ckeditor/pictures#destroy
attachment_files GET    /attachment_files(.:format)     ckeditor/attachment_files#index
                 POST   /attachment_files(.:format)     ckeditor/attachment_files#create
 attachment_file DELETE /attachment_files/:id(.:format) ckeditor/attachment_files#destroy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted heroku support and they had a similar answer to @AjitSingh in recommending I use AJAX:

> I see what you mean. Rather than relying on  tags, I would suggest
>   making AJAX calls to do a proper POST request, using buttons or forms.

However, AJAX is a bit above my skill level right now.  I also found this little gem (no pun intended) on the ROR API about using `link_to`:

> method: symbol of HTTP verb - This modifier will dynamically create an
>   HTML form and immediately submit the form for processing using the
>   HTTP verb specified. Useful for having links perform a POST operation
>   in dangerous actions like deleting a record (which search bots can
>   follow while spidering your site). Supported verbs are :post, :delete,
>   :patch, and :put. Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the
>   request will fall back to using GET. If href: '#' is used and the user
>   has JavaScript disabled clicking the link will have no effect. If you
>   are relying on the POST behavior, you should check for it in your
>   controller's action by using the request object's methods for post?,
>   delete?, patch?, or put?.

Finally, I ended up consulting the advice of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799541/rails-3-method-post-doesnt-work-seems-to-be-get-when-it-should-po) SO post and using `button_to` instead of `link_to` and it fixed the issue.  Whew.

Answer (score 0):

It's submitting a 'get' request and needs to be submitting a post request.  Be sure you specify `method: :post` in your link_to call that handles "up votes".

Comment: Unfortunately, my `link_to` DOES specify `method: :post`.  That's what's weird.  I updated the OP with the HTML/erb...

Comment: Can you paste the output when you run "bundle exec rake routes" in your console?

Comment: I added it to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have following in your application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

`jquery-ujs` makes non-GET requests from hyperlinks. Even if `link_to` method produces proper html with `data-method=post` you need `jquery-ujs` to make non-GET requests other wise your links will naturally create GET request.

Comment: Both are required.

Answer (score 0):

I am 99% sure that link_to will always generate a get request, regardless you put a method :post in it.

Can you please share you log file details?

Here is something I tried on my end:

```
= link_to "Test", "/public/create", method: :post
```

And here is my log output:

- Started GET "/public/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-13 18:22:18 +0000

here is my route:

```
  root to: 'public#index'
  post "public/create", to: "public#create"
```

Comment: Not true.  Links are used in delete requests in many occasions as well.  In the docs, link_to will convert itself dynamically into a form when passed an HTTP Verb.  "method: symbol of HTTP verb - This modifier will dynamically create an HTML form and immediately submit the form for processing using the HTTP verb specified. Useful for having links perform a POST operation in dangerous actions like deleting a record (which search bots can follow while spidering your site)."

Comment: I think you are right. Not sure why I got "get" request in logs though my link is specified as "post". something to experiment with.

Comment: Yes, right after the error it says `Started GET "/jokes/1/vote_up" for 70.181.88.50 at 2016-10-13 23:42:58 +0000`

Comment: There you go. It is making a GET request, even though your method type is POST. I am not sure what other possible solution you can implement. But the one I will use would be Javascript based POST.

Track the click even, use javascript to intercept and make a POST using AJAX. I hope this helps